# $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ complex differentiable only at the origin?

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried finding $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$, $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$, and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ to check the Cauchy-Riemann equations, and this is what I got:

$$f(x+yi)=\frac{1+x^2-y^2-2xyi}{(1+x^2-y^2)^2+2xy}$$
so clearly
$$u(x, y)=\frac{1+x^2-y^2}{(1+x^2-y^2)^2+2xy}$$
$$v(x, y)=\frac{-2xyi}{(1+x^2-y^2)^2+2xy}$$
which gives
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{-2 x^5 + 4 x^3 y^2 - 4 x^3 + 2 x^2 y - 2 x y^4 + 4 x y^2 - 2 x + 2 y^3 - 2 y}{((1+x^2-y^2)^2+2xy)^2}
$$
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=\frac{-2 x^5 - 4 x^3 y^2 - 4 x^3 + 6 x y^4 - 4 x y^2 - 2 x}{((1+x^2-y^2)^2+2xy)^2}$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{2 x^4 y - 2 x^3 - 4 x^2 y^3 + 4 x^2 y - 2 x y^2 - 2 x + 2 y^5 - 4 y^3 + 2 y}{((1+x^2-y^2)^2+2xy)^2}
$$
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\frac{6 x^4 y - 4 x^2 y^3 + 4 x^2 y - 2 y^5 + 4 y^3 - 2 y}{((1+x^2-y^2)^2+2xy)^2}$$

Which implies Cauchy-Riemann only holds at the origin. Am I correct that this function is only differentiable when $z=0+0i$? Is there a more reasonable way to come to this solution?

Comment: No, $1/(1+z^2)$ is differentiable for $z\ne\pm i$. I'd advise seeking an error in your calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a more reasonable way to come to this solution?

Definitely.

Maybe the first one that comes to mind is the following: the function $w\mapsto f(z+w)$ can be expanded as a series in $w$ around every point $z$ of its domain of definition (that is, at every $z\ne\pm i$), hence $f$ is holomorphic on this domain, thus $f$ is complex differentiable on this domain.

A second one: the function $f$ is the composition of the functions $g:z\mapsto1+z^2$, which is complex differentiable everywhere as a polynomial, and the function $h:z\mapsto1/z$, which is complex differentiable everywhere except at $z=0$ by a direct computation, hence $f=h\circ g$ is complex differentiable everywhere except at $g^{-1}(\{0\})=\{\pm i\}$.

The computations needed in the second approach are especially reduced since one simply writes, for every $z\ne0$ and every $|w|<|z|$, $$\frac{h(z+w)-h(z)}w=\frac1w\left(\frac1{z+w}-\frac1z\right)=-\frac1{z(z+w)}$$ hence $$\frac{h(z+w)-h(z)}w\underset{w\to0}{\longrightarrow}-\frac1{z^2}$$ *...et voilà!*

Answer (score 1):

Your first line should be
$$f(x+yi)=\frac{1+x^2-y^2-2xyi}{(1+x^2-y^2)^2+(2xy)^2}.$$